Unable to guess the MIME type as no guessers are available
i just deployed laravel project online and all is fine except when i try to post a file i get the error, -> Unable to guess the MIME type as no guessers are available (have you enabled the php_fileinfo extension?). I don`t know what is missing i will appreciate any help.
I tried reaching out to the hosting provider but could not get any help from their side

have you enabled the php_fileinfo extension seems telling. Is the extension installed?

@aynber I cant find php_fileinfo extension in cpanel, tried multiPHP INI Editor, can not see the option for ebabling...

It will most likely just be listed as fileinfo.

Thanks for the reply @aynber, i think the extension is not installed on the server

You'll need to contact your web host to see if it can be installed, then.
